# AppBarButtonStyle: Changing Content from code

Tags: c#

How to change Content of Button which style is AppBarButtonStyle from code-behind? I would like to change an icon and I do it like that:

```
private void ChangemyButtonIcon()
{
   myButton.SetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty, "new text");
   myButton.Content = "&#xE15D;"; // <--- works wrong
}
```

but then instead of standard icon inside button text displays.

Do you know how to do it in right way?
Thank you in advance for help
Maciek

Answer (score 4):

U can do like that

```
<Style x:Key="MusicOffButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="MusicOffButton"/>
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Music OFF"/>
<Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MusicOnButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="MusicOnButton"/>
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Music ON"/>
<Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
</Style>

private void SetMusicButtonIcon()
{
MusicButton.Style = (ifMuted) ? (this.Resources["MusicOffButtonStyle"] as Style) : (this.Resources["MusicOnButtonStyle"] as Style);

}
```